# IOS Browser Masquerading

Tags: macos, ios, safari

Is there a simple way to task the IOS Safari browser to masquerade as an OS X Safari Browser?  I understand that Win-tel browser have this capability and thought that Safari might have similar capability for testing purposes

Answer (score 3):

In recent versions of iOS you can request a desktop site in Mobile Safari.
Long-press/hold the `reload` control icon (see annotated screenshot below) in the address bar until a dialog pops up, then select "Request Desktop Site".

The user agent changes from iPhone OS (e.g. mobile OS) to Intel Mac OS X (e.g. desktop OS).

(Screenshots below show a German user agent check webpage, but you get the idea.)

Mobile Safari: "regular" iOS user agent
[image: Mobile Safari iOS user agent]

Mobile Safari: desktop Mac user agent after "Request Desktop Site"
[image: Mobile Safari Mac user agent]

Comment: Excellent use of annotated photos to clarify a good explanation.  Thank you